# Checkstyle for ActionScript (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, coding-style

HI,
I'm currently working on a project that uses Flex and Java. In Java we easily enforced a coding standard with Checkstyle, and we want to do this for Flex.

Does anybody know of a tool similar to Checkstyle that would allow coding standard checks?
(I've googled for this but found only one project written in python and it seams abandoned)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long and the short is that there is... kind of, but only for Actionscript, and you have to test it yourself...  There is a [prototype](http://code.google.com/p/checkstyleas3/downloads/list) of an Actionscript 3 version, but it is not even in Beta yet (and I admit that I haven't had the time to test it).  I haven't found anything similar for XML, let alone MXML.  This is in at least one list of [feature requests](http://clintm.esria.com/2007/12/10/flex-builder-4-feature-wish-list/) for Flex 4, however.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working too on a project uses Flex and Java. Like you, in Java, we easily use plugins like checkstyle, findBug, javaNcss or PMD. My personal project is to do this for Flex. I have test the prototype 'checkStyleas3' but it just verify the code source en returns you  0 or -1  as result. So you will have (me too in fact), to implement this prototype if you want to do more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an eye on this : http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2009/05/20/as3v-preview/