# Coding constraints checker?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, coding-style, static-analysis

Please help me to get a coding  constraints for action script and flex 3.

Regards,
Lalji

Comment: Bit more detail please, A LOT more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Similar stuff here, [Checkstyle for ActionScript (Flex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462770/checkstyle-for-actionscript-flex)